# AngularJS redirect to view after data save

Tags: angularjs, redirect, controller, factory

After saving data from the employee-maintenance view, I am trying to redirect to the employee-details view. I want to do this within the controller's success method:

```
$scope.insertEmployee = function (employee) {
    if (employee && $scope.IsNew) {
        employeeFactory.insertEmployee(employee)
            .success(function (data) {
                // after a successful save, redirect the user to the details view
                $location.path('/employee-details/' + employee.EmployeeNumber);
                if (!$scope.$$phase)
                    $scope.$apply()
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to save the employee data: ' + error;
            });
    }
    else {
        $scope.status = 'You are missing required information!';
    }
};
```

Here is my factory:

```
factory.insertEmployee = function (employee) {
    url = baseAddress + "employee/insert/";
    return $http.post(url, employee);
};
```

My asp.net webapi controller:

```
    [Route("api/employee/insert/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Employee employee)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        // check for the employee
        Employee employeeCheck = employeeService.GetEmployeeById(employee.EmployeeNumber);
        if (employeeCheck == null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                employeeService.CreateEmployee(employee);
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "There was a problem with saving the data.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "The item already exists");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

This question appears to have been asked quite often but none of the solutions have worked for me.

**Edit:** I used the following instead of $location.path()

```
window.location.href = 'Index.html#/employee-details/' + employee.EmployeeNumber;
```

which worked, but it also generate an ugly runtime error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. It appears in order to use $location.path, you have to add $locationProvider to your app module config:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/ViewStart.html'
    })
```

Then, in your controller you inject $location:

```
app.controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, employeeFactory, $location)
```

Finally, you can set the path:

```
$scope.insertEmployee = function (employee) {
    if (employee && $scope.IsNew) {
        employeeFactory.insertEmployee(employee)
            .success(function () {
                $scope.status = 'The item was saved!';
                $location.path('/employee-details/' + employee.EmployeeNumber);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to save the employee data: ' + error;
            });
    }
    else {
        $scope.status = 'You are missing required information!';
    }
};
```

Now, when I am on the edit page and click save, it redirects to the details view for that specific employee